# Scanner Two-dimensional array (n x n)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] num = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)
            if (i == j)
                num[i][j] = 1;
            else
                num[i][j] = 0;

    for (int[] a : num) {
        for (int b : a)
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

i want to make
1   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   1
but my answer come out like
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 0; j++)` - j < 0 ? typo

Comment: A remark on your code: even in situations possible, you should not omit the parentheses surrounding `if`, `else`, `for`,... This can introduce nasty bugs when you edit/extend your code later on.

Comment: In addition, what you want (100010001) does not look like a 2 dim array. Your code will generate a matrix with 1 at the diagonal entries

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is kicking out of the inner loop, the one using `j` as the variable. You initialize `j = 0`, and then if j < 0 it will execute. However, 0 < 0 is false so it never iterates thru the inner loop. Try changing that line to 
`for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)` and I'll expect you'll get the result you are looking for.

Comment: thank i did't see that i thought i put it in to n not 0 zzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop through all elements in 2d array not just the 0th element. see modified for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] num = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (i == j)
                num[i][j] = 1;
            else
                num[i][j] = 0;

    for (int[] a : num) {
        for (int b : a)
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```